# How to fetch all information about spl token with token address in anchor or in javascript

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program, spl-associated-token-account, anchor-spl, spl-token-cli

i want to fetch token information of spl token directly from the solana blockchain . Give some solution to fetch **metadata , tokenomics data and security data** of spl token .
i want to fetch directly from the blockchain with the help of anchor or with javascript

Comment: What do you mean by tokenomics data and security?